# How to make a virtual host public with LAMPP?

Tags: package-management, apache2, lamp

Together with a friend we have designed a web page with html, css and js and to publish it we thought about using the Apache server on Linux. We bought a Raspberry Pi4, downloaded everything, transferred the files to the Raspberry and everything was fine. We configure the static IP using commands and it works. We created a domain to view the website on a local network and now we are ready to publish it to view it from a global network and removing the admin part in the /etc/apache2/sites-available configuration files. And an error happens to us which is that if we enter the IP from another device on another network, the default Apache Index appears in the browser. But if we enter the domain we entered, it tells us that that page cannot be accessed. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thank you

Comment: Please translate into English. This site does not support other languages.

Comment: Okey, thanks, now?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please, edit you question and add more details about how you configured your domain name. Also share the content of your config file/files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`